# Is there verification on Sigstore when downloading dependencies from Maven?

Tags: maven, verification

By using the Maven sigstore plugin, the Maven projects can be signed and deployed. So, on the other hand, is there a way to verify those signatures when it comes to downloading a package from Maven? Is Maven doing that when download?

I tried sigstore by signing a package and deploying it to maven, but was unable to verify when downloading.